# choose language to draw map & show few ares with an icon

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, maps

I am new to web technologies, I started looking into HTML, CSS, Java script (I am familiar with these now).

Now I wanted to draw a map (ex: google maps of a certain city) & want to mark my own locations (ex: I want to show all petrol bunks in my city with small petrol bunk Icon) .

So for the above requirement what language and technologies I can use.
can above thing be achieved with the help of HTML & Java script. or do I need to learn & use any other thing.  my apologies if i use wrong terminology I am new to web technologies.

Please suggest.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to draw interactive map of fuel sites in your city is using google maps api. You should start here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/
And javascript is definitely the language you are looking for. You also gonna need coordinates of every fuel site in your city

this is my example of such map: 
https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/viewer?mid=1DLGEGzVNBf7IbKZ1h1j-wdI4-vA

I created it using google maps constructor and than placed it on my client's site.